# How can I extract the encrypted master key from LUKS header?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, luks, dm-crypt

I know that a LUKS partition has a plain-text header that stores many informations like master key (MK) digest, MK iterations of PBKDF2, information about the 8 key-slots etc. I also know that in the header there is the af-splitted and encrypted master key.

I'm asking if there is a way to recover that. I know I could simply use:

```
cryptsetup luksDump --dump-master-key /dev/whatever
```

However, this only give me the decrypted MK.

---

Only information I have are from header:

key-material-offset: 8 (start sector of key material)

number of stripes: 4000

My goal would be to manually decrypt the master key with the derived key from pbkdf2, do af-merge and then decrypt the whole data bulk with this candidate key.

Comment: read the relevant position of your hard drive?

Comment: Yes but the mk is stripped and I don't know how. 

I edited the question with more infos.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is what you want. It creates a copy of the header, without making any assumptions about the header size.

```
# cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sda5 --header-backup-file /tmp/luks-header
```

But I'm not sure if I 100% understand your question. Are you asking how to extract the LUKS header including the master key, or *just* the encrypted master key and nothing else?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can mount the LUKS volume, do this when it is mounted:

```
 $ dmsetup table --showkey myvolume
 0 200704 crypt aes-xts-plain64 0ef81...9aef7 0 8:18 4096
```

The long string is the master key.

But this is the same as

```
$ cryptsetup luksDump --dump-master-key /dev/myrawvolume
MK dump: 0e f8 1. .. .. ..
         .. .. .. .9 ae f7
```

So I am not sure what your're asking...

[I wrote a program](https://github.com/johnlane/random-toolbox/blob/master/usr/bin/luksdump) ages ago which dumps out a LUKS key, it's written in Ruby and might be handy if you're trying to understand how to perform the necessary steps to extract the key.

Answer (score 0):

This would dump the entire LUKS header, which includes the encrypted key:

```
dd if=/dev/whatever bs=2M count=1 of=luks-header.img
```

Comment: Depending on drive layout, LUKS version, and partition scheme, this will not always work.

Comment: My luks header have 2.1MB so this command won't work in my case. I suggest to use @forest method or set a safer value like 32MB